# Bash Shell Script if statement issue and cp/date command issues

Tags: bash, unix

I am new to UNIX and am having some issues with my bash script and would like some help. My script is designed to copy files from one directory to a target directory while outputting which files are being copied, the current date each file is being copied, and an error message if not enough parameters/input from the user.

So far, I have three parameters/arguments. 1)sourcePath which is the directory that has files. 2)backupPath, the directory the user wants to copy files to from sourcePath (if backupPath is not a directory, then it will automatically be made), and 3)filePrefix which prompts the user to enter a certain letter or pattern and any file from sourcePath that starts with that letter or has that pattern will be copied. Couple of issues so far are that the files being copied are not being displayed, so the user doesn't know which files were copied until they `cd` into the backupPath directory and `ls` to see. The second problem is the current date not showing. The third problem is that I have an if statement for if not enough paramteters have been passed that will echo a certain message, but that message is echoed no matter what, even if all parameters have been given. Code is below:

```
read -r -p "sourcePath: "  sourcePath
read -r -p "backupPath: " backupPath
read -r -p "filePrefix: " filePrefix

if [ $# -lt 3 ]; then
  echo "Create backup files in a target directory given
the target directory name and a file name prefix.
Only files found in the specified source directory
whose name begins with the supplied prefix will
be copied. In addition, all copied echo files will
have a datestamp suffix added.
 syntax: ./dobackup.bash sourcePath backupPath filePrefix"
fi

mkdir -p /home/public/"$backupPath"
cp -v /export/home/public/"$sourcePath/$filePrefix"* `(date +%y%m%d)`
```

So as said above, `"cp -v"` seems to not be working properly as it lists every file in the backupPath and sourcePath directories when it is to only display files being copied.

My if statement outputs whenever the script is executed, when it should only output if not all of the parameters/inputs have been met, or typed in by the user. I understand this is a lot of help to ask for but I am still new to UNIX and scripting. I know how to do all of this if I was to just input the separate commands myself but am having difficulties here. All help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you're confusing the script's parameters (e.g. `./dobackup.bash sourcePath backupPath filePrefix`, which are accessed via `$1`, `$2`, etc) with things it read *after starting* (which `read` does). Also, `cp` copies *all* files it's told to copy (if there's already a file by that name in the destination, it replaces it).

Comment: Yes I did just notice that. The way I have it currently setup, the user will enter three inputs one at a time. Either way, the if statement should only occur if the user does not enter something for each input, but it if statement still executes even if the user enters information for all three inputs, which is the issue I am having.

Comment: No, you're still confusing arguments with the things that're `read`. `$#` counts the parameters/arguments provided on the command line, and has nothing whatsoever to do with what the user enters in response to the `read` commands.

Comment: Oh okay I get you. Do you think I should delete the first few lines and replace them with "$sourcePath $backupPath $filePrefix" to make the if function execute properly or am I still not understanding this correctly?

Comment: It'd be more like `sourcePath=$1`, `backupPath=$2`, and `filePrefix=$3` (and I'd put that *after* the check on `$#`, because there's no point in copying the arguments into variables unless they actually exist).

Comment: The code in the question seems to be a somewhat garbled version of the code provided as an answer to [Bash Shell Script Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71301508/4154375).  I suspect it's not the code that's actually being run though because the `cp` command doesn't involve `$backupPath` at all, so there's no way it could list files in that directory.  Please put your real code in the question.  Also, please run it through [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and fix any problems that it finds before posting it.  That will eliminate obvious bugs and save time for everybody.

Comment: This might be useful for you: [Handling positional parameters - Bash Hackers Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams).

Comment: pjh, I actually forgot to inclue that part. The last line is actually cp -v /export/home/public/"$sourcepath/$filePrefix"* /home/public/"$backupPath"